# Scatter Plot Only Plots the last iteration

Tags: python

I am trying to plot several different things in scatter plots by having several subplots and iterating over. Here in an example of what the result actually look like:

```
('x out: ', ' -511', ' y out: ', '    1')
('Magnitudo = ', 4.778809128414475)
[0.]
('x out: ', ' -511', ' y out: ', ' -255')
('Magnitudo = ', 5.9840357600793475)
[1.]
('x out: ', ' -511', ' y out: ', '    1')
('Magnitudo = ', 5.474086008639472)
[0.]
('x out: ', '  513', ' y out: ', ' -511')
('Magnitudo = ', 5.182103409440737)
[0.]
('x out: ', ' -511', ' y out: ', '  513')
('Magnitudo = ', 5.1769691160028835)
[0.]
('x out: ', ' -255', ' y out: ', ' -511')
('Magnitudo = ', 6.559643742815329)
[1.]
```

And this is the matplot I generated:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqRzo.jpg)

As you can see, the matplot only shows the last iteration of my result. How do I present all of my iteration into this graph? Thank you. Here's my code. Where did I go wrong?

```
print ("Gyroskop")
print ("--------")
i="TRUE"
j = 0
mag = []
with open("/home/pi/TA/accelero.csv") as csvFile:
    while i == "TRUE":
        gyroskop_xout1 = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyroskop_yout1 = read_word_2c(0x45)
        acc1 = math.sqrt((gyroskop_xout1*gyroskop_xout1)+(gyroskop_yout1*gyroskop_yout1))

        mag.append(acc1)
        print ("x out: ", ("%5d" % gyroskop_xout1), " y out: ",("%5d" % gyroskop_yout1))
        j=j+1
        time.sleep(1)
    #---------------------
        gyroskop_xout2 = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyroskop_yout2 = read_word_2c(0x45)
        acc2 = math.sqrt((gyroskop_xout2*gyroskop_xout2)+(gyroskop_yout2*gyroskop_yout2))

        mag.append(acc2)
        time.sleep(1)
    #--------------------
        mag_max = max(mag)
        mag_min = min(mag)
        amplitude = mag_max - mag_min
#        print "A : ",amplitude
        h = amplitude/0.001
#        print h
#        print abs(h)
        M_richter = 0
        if(h!=0):
            M_richter = math.log10(abs(h))
        print ("Magnitudo = ",(M_richter))
        #mag.clear()
        del mag [:]
        #accel = deltaM /2
        hasil=clf.predict([[1, M_richter]])
        print(hasil)
        if (M_richter >= 6):

            while aaa<5:
                GPIO.output(buzzer,GPIO.HIGH)
                print ("Beep")
                sleep(0.5) # Delay in seconds
                GPIO.output(buzzer,GPIO.LOW)
                #print ("No Beep")
                sleep(0.5)
                aaa=aaa+1
                csvFile.close()
            i = "False" 
        if j == 10:
          i = "False"    


X0, X1  = 1, M_richter
plt.scatter(X0,X1, color = 'G')
plt.title('linear SVC')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('Location')

plt.show()
```

Y is 1 by default and I want to show all my magnitudo, thank you.

Comment: put  code lines X0, X1 .. and plt.scatter(X0 ... into while loop

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only passing a single point value (X0,X1) to plt.scatter(). You need to pass it a list of values, for example:

```
plt.scatter([x1,x2,x3,x4], [y1,y2,y3,y4], color = 'G')
```

However, I'm not completely sure what you are trying to plot here? If you want to plot the magnitude (`M_richter`) vs. the index `j` you have to append the calculated `M_richter` in each iteration to a list and then pass the list to plt.scatter(), and do the same with the values of `j`. Your script would then look like:

```
print ("Gyroskop")
print ("--------")
i="TRUE"
j = 0
mag = []
M_richter_values = []
j_values = []
with open("/home/pi/TA/accelero.csv") as csvFile:
    while i == "TRUE":
        gyroskop_xout1 = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyroskop_yout1 = read_word_2c(0x45)
        acc1 = math.sqrt((gyroskop_xout1*gyroskop_xout1)+(gyroskop_yout1*gyroskop_yout1))

        mag.append(acc1)
        print ("x out: ", ("%5d" % gyroskop_xout1), " y out: ",("%5d" % gyroskop_yout1))

        j_values.append(j)          # Append value of j to list
        j=j+1
        time.sleep(1)
    #---------------------
        gyroskop_xout2 = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyroskop_yout2 = read_word_2c(0x45)
        acc2 = math.sqrt((gyroskop_xout2*gyroskop_xout2)+(gyroskop_yout2*gyroskop_yout2))

        mag.append(acc2)
        time.sleep(1)
    #--------------------
        mag_max = max(mag)
        mag_min = min(mag)
        amplitude = mag_max - mag_min
#        print "A : ",amplitude
        h = amplitude/0.001
#        print h
#        print abs(h)
        M_richter = 0
        if(h!=0):
            M_richter = math.log10(abs(h))
        print ("Magnitudo = ",(M_richter))
        M_richter_values.append(M_richter)     # Append to list
        #mag.clear()
        del mag [:]
        #accel = deltaM /2
        hasil=clf.predict([[1, M_richter]])
        print(hasil)
        if (M_richter >= 6):

            while aaa<5:
                GPIO.output(buzzer,GPIO.HIGH)
                print ("Beep")
                sleep(0.5) # Delay in seconds
                GPIO.output(buzzer,GPIO.LOW)
                #print ("No Beep")
                sleep(0.5)
                aaa=aaa+1
                csvFile.close()
            i = "False" 
        if j == 10:
          i = "False"    


X0, X1  = 1, M_richter
plt.scatter(j_values, M_richter_values, color = 'G')   # Passing lists instead of scalars
plt.title('linear SVC')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.xlabel('Location')

plt.show()
```